# Account Apex Trigger Help

Tags: apex, trigger, npsp

I'm trying to prevent the deletion of accounts if one of the contacts within the account has a "Do Not Delete" checkbox as true. Here's a trigger (My very first one!)

Please let me know if this is even possible. it isn't throwing any error when I delete an account with the contact DnD checked

```
trigger prevdeletion on Account (before delete)
     {for (Account a:trigger.old){
    ID accountId;
    List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>([SELECT Id, Name,Do_Not_Delete__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :accountId]);
        for(Contact c:Contacts){
            if(c.Do_Not_Delete__c=Boolean.valueOf('true') ){
                a.adderror('Account cannot be deleted because child contact is protected.');
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have initialized `accountId` with the Account's Id. You need something as `accountId = a.Id` and then utilize that in the SOQL.

Comment: Looks like you've accidentally created [duplicate accounts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265068/how-to-prevent-account-deletion-based-on-contact-field). Please use the Contact link at the bottom of every page to request that they be merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have not initialized the `accountId` which is used in your SOQL as below to fetch the Contacts and thus you are not getting any results.

```
ID accountId; // this is not assigned to the intended account's id
List<Contact> contacts = 
    new List<Contact>(
       [SELECT Id, Name,Do_Not_Delete__c 
        FROM Contact 
        WHERE AccountId = :accountId]); // issue here
```

Then, as David as highlighted you are using `=` which won't compare the value but assign the result of `Boolean.valueOf('true')` to the field's value. You will need to use `==` for comparison without the need of using `Boolean.valueOf` as long as the field is a Boolean field.

While you can fix the issue by assigning `accountId = a.Id` and addressing other issues of querying all Contacts and then iterating through those to find the field's value, a better approach here would be to utilize [**Aggregate Function**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm).

Your overall code could look as:

```
AggregateResult[] contactCounts = 
    [SELECT AccountId, COUNT(Id) 
     FROM Contact 
     WHERE Do_Not_Delete__c = TRUE 
         AND AccountId IN :Trigger.oldMap.keySet() 
     GROUP BY AccountId];

// now put all account ids and their respective contact counts in a map
Map<Id, Integer> accountContactCount = new Map<Id, Integer>();
for (AggregateResult ar : contactCounts)  {
    accountContactCount.put(ar.get('AccountId'), ar.get('expr0'));
}

// now iterate through the trigger records and verify if contact exists, then add error
for (Account a : trigger.old) {
    if(accountContactCount.get(a.Id) > 0) {
        a.adderror('Account cannot be deleted because child contact is protected.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you have a couple of issues with your trigger.

### Apex Issues

```
ID accountId;
```

This variable is uninitialized, so it defaults to `null`.

```
List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>([SELECT Id, Name,Do_Not_Delete__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :accountId]);
```

Then, this query is locating Contacts whose Account is ... `null`. That's not what you want here. Instead, use `:a.Id`, but see below for more on bulkification.

```
if(c.Do_Not_Delete__c=Boolean.valueOf('true') ){
```

1. `if` statements evaluate Booleans already, so you just need to evaluate the Boolean variable `c.Do_Not_Delete__c`:

   ```
   if(c.Do_Not_Delete__c){
   ```
2. You can write literal Booleans in Apex: `true` and `false`. No need for `Boolean.valueOf()`.
3. You've accidentally written an assignment statement with a single equals sign, `=`. `==` is what you need for comparison.

### Bulkification Issues

As written, your code runs one query per Account. That will throw a limit exception if 100 Accounts are deleted. I strongly recommend completing the [Bulk Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) module on Trailhead to learn bulkification patterns.

Here, luckily, the fix is pretty easy. Just do a parent-child subquery:

```
 for (Account a : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Name,Do_Not_Delete__c FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :Trigger.oldMap.keySet()]) {
    for(Contact c: a.Contacts) {
```

Then your logic goes in the inner `for` loop, but you only run a single query for the entire trigger set.